# how to convert stringyfied array values into float in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have used **data_str = JSON.stringify(data);** to convert into string. the data in json is

```
[{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371996","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171424","timestamp2":"1493270171454","timestamp3":"1493270171454","val":"0"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137112","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171522","timestamp3":"1493270171523","val":"1"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371186","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171523","timestamp3":"1493270171524","val":"2"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371595","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171524","timestamp3":"1493270171525","val":"3"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137168","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529","val":"4"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371684","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529","val":"5"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371357","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171429","timestamp2":"1493270171530","timestamp3":"1493270171531","val":"6"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371144","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171429","timestamp2":"1493270171531","timestamp3":"1493270171532","val":"7"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137181","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171431","timestamp2":"1493270171546","timestamp3":"1493270171546","val":"25"}]
```

Now I want to take **timestamp** value and perform some mathematical operations.How to convert this into Float values?
Even Though I used **parseInt(timestamp)** and **Number(timestamp)**, it is not working and showing me result: **NaN**.

Comment: What are you trying to do when you get NaN? Doing for example `parseInt(data[0]["timestamp"]` is just giving you a number, which is also a floating-point value.

Comment: you need a float values use `parseFloat(data.timestamp)`

Comment: Actually, the problem is I am storing JSON data in a .json file. Every time the data keep on adding up(real time data). So reading "timestamp" each time from a file is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = [{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371996","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171424","timestamp2":"1493270171454","timestamp3":"1493270171454","val":"0"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137112","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171522","timestamp3":"1493270171523","val":"1"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371186","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171523","timestamp3":"1493270171524","val":"2"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371595","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171524","timestamp3":"1493270171525","val":"3"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137168","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529","val":"4"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371684","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529","val":"5"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371357","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171429","timestamp2":"1493270171530","timestamp3":"1493270171531","val":"6"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371144","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171429","timestamp2":"1493270171531","timestamp3":"1493270171532","val":"7"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137181","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171431","timestamp2":"1493270171546","timestamp3":"1493270171546","val":"25"}];

console.log(jsonObj.map(item => parseFloat(item.timestamp)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try parseFloat("28.489084691371996") function. It will help you.

```
parseFloat("28.489084691371996")
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

parseFloat() -
[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
var arr = [{
"temperSensorData": "28.489084691371996", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171424", "timestamp2": "1493270171454", "timestamp3": "1493270171454", "val": "0"
}, {
"temperSensorData": "28.48908469137112", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171426", "timestamp2": "1493270171522", "timestamp3": "1493270171523", "val": "1"
}, {
"temperSensorData": "28.489084691371186", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171426", "timestamp2": "1493270171523", "timestamp3": "1493270171524", "val": "2"
}, {
"temperSensorData": "28.489084691371595", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171426", "timestamp2": "1493270171524", "timestamp3": "1493270171525", "val": "3"
}, {
"temperSensorData": "28.48908469137168", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171428", "timestamp2": "1493270171529", "timestamp3": "1493270171529", "val": "4"
}, {
"temperSensorData": "28.489084691371684", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171428", "timestamp2": "1493270171529", "timestamp3": "1493270171529", "val": "5"
}, {
"temperSensorData": "28.489084691371357", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171429", "timestamp2": "1493270171530", "timestamp3": "1493270171531", "val": "6"
}, {
"temperSensorData": "28.489084691371144", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171429", "timestamp2": "1493270171531", "timestamp3": "1493270171532", "val": "7"
 }, {
"temperSensorData": "28.48908469137181", "temperSensorUnit": "celsius", "timestamp": "1493270171431", "timestamp2": "1493270171546", "timestamp3": "1493270171546", "val": "25"
 }]


var t = arr.map(x=>{
    return parseFloat(x.timestamp)
})

console.log(t)
```

Result

```
[ 1493270171424,
  1493270171426,
  1493270171426,
  1493270171426,
  1493270171428,
  1493270171428,
  1493270171429,
  1493270171429,
  1493270171431 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

use  **`parseFloat(data.timestamp)`**  instead of `parseInt` and `timestamp` is the inner object value of data json array .you could call like this `data.timestamp`
i was create some map function to separate `timestamp` and append with in a array

```js
var data = [{
  "temperSensorData": "28.489084691371996",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171424",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171454",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171454",
  "val": "0"
}, {
  "temperSensorData": "28.48908469137112",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171426",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171522",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171523",
  "val": "1"
}, {
  "temperSensorData": "28.489084691371186",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171426",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171523",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171524",
  "val": "2"
}, {
  "temperSensorData": "28.489084691371595",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171426",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171524",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171525",
  "val": "3"
}, {
  "temperSensorData": "28.48908469137168",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171428",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171529",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171529",
  "val": "4"
}, {
  "temperSensorData": "28.489084691371684",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171428",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171529",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171529",
  "val": "5"
}, {
  "temperSensorData": "28.489084691371357",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171429",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171530",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171531",
  "val": "6"
}, {
  "temperSensorData": "28.489084691371144",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171429",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171531",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171532",
  "val": "7"
}, {
  "temperSensorData": "28.48908469137181",
  "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
  "timestamp": "1493270171431",
  "timestamp2": "1493270171546",
  "timestamp3": "1493270171546",
  "val": "25"
}]

console.log(data.map(a=> parseFloat(a.timestamp)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It´s a good way to convert the JSON to an object...

Sample:

```
data_str=JSON.parse('[{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371996","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171424","timestamp2":"1493270171454","timestamp3":"1493270171454","val":"0"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137112","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171522","timestamp3":"1493270171523","val":"1"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371186","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171523","timestamp3":"1493270171524","val":"2"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371595","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171524","timestamp3":"1493270171525","val":"3"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137168","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529","val":"4"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371684","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529","val":"5"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371357","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171429","timestamp2":"1493270171530","timestamp3":"1493270171531","val":"6"},{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371144","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171429","timestamp2":"1493270171531","timestamp3":"1493270171532","val":"7"},{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137181","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171431","timestamp2":"1493270171546","timestamp3":"1493270171546","val":"25"}]');
console.log (data_str.length);

console.log (data_str[0].temperSensorData);
console.log(parseFloat(data_str[0].temperSensorData));

myTimeStamp = parseInt(data_str[0].timestamp);
console.log(myTimeStamp);


var theDate = new Date(myTimeStamp);
dateString = theDate.toString();
console.log(dateString);
```